# Add new table with SUMMARIZE (need distinct values)

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a large data sheet, from this I have generated a new table in PowerBI via the summarize function. But I would like to have it return distinct values for the 'project number'.

My current formula looks like this:

```
New table=SUMMARIZE (
    TABLE1,
    TABLE1[project_code],
        "Start Date", MIN ( TABLE1[fpi_date].[Date] ),
    "End Date", MAX ( TABLE1[lpi_date].[Date] )
)
```

Comment: Is `project number` different than `project_code`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the [DISTINCT()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee634943.aspx) or [VALUES()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee634547.aspx) function.

Edit:
When I try you code, it already returns distinct values for the project code. Do you have sample data?

Comment: Hi, yes I also realized that, my problem was null values! thanks